# Enscroll jQuery Plug In

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I've been trying to implement Enscroll Plug in into a Bootstrap page, but I haven't gotten Facebook Ticker Scrollbar that is shown in their demo's page to function right. I was wondering if anyone will be able to help me out and look at my code, and see what I am doing wrong in my syntax, and explain to me what I am doing wrong.

```js
$('#scrollbox3').enscroll({
  showOnHover: true,
  verticalTrackClass: 'track3',
  verticalHandleClass: 'handle3'
});
```

```css
#scrollbox3 {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 360px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
}
.track3 {
  width: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  margin-right: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background 250ms linear;
  transition: background 250ms linear;
}
.track3:hover,
.track3.dragging {
  background: #d9d9d9;
  /* Browsers without rgba support */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.handle3 {
  width: 7px;
  right: 0;
  background: #999;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-transition: width 250ms;
  transition: width 250ms;
}
.track3:hover .handle3,
.track3.dragging .handle3 {
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://enscrollplugin.com/releases/enscroll-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="scrollbox3">
        <h1>New Scrolling Window</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a justo erat, volutpat hendrerit dolor. Sed urna nibh, dapibus at egestas non, vulputate ut quam. Morbi a erat tristique tellus varius venenatis. Aenean lacinia sem eget turpis fringilla
          commodo. Sed lorem nisi, viverra a interdum nec, varius eu enim. Donec ornare, nunc quis eleifend iaculis, nulla eros mollis tellus, quis faucibus risus odio non lectus. Maecenas ac velit non metus rhoncus commodo. Nunc ligula est, ultricies
          sed mattis sed, dapibus at arcu. Maecenas lacinia nisl ut sem bibendum ac condimentum purus facilisis. Curabitur ut nibh lobortis libero interdum vehicula vel quis nulla.</p>

        <p>Suspendisse et massa urna. Donec eu lorem nec felis dapibus aliquam viverra in quam. Suspendisse ultrices, nisi ac venenatis porttitor, erat turpis dapibus augue, sed rutrum nunc ante sed enim. Aliquam et tempus mi. Nullam malesuada, nunc a eleifend
          pretium, justo lorem tempus justo, id adipiscing dolor ipsum sed velit. Maecenas odio massa, feugiat vel sodales ut, placerat at quam. Cras viverra diam vitae diam elementum vitae aliquet erat tincidunt. Quisque fringilla neque in lacus tempor
          cursus. Curabitur eget nulla et nisi dignissim tempor vel non risus. Mauris ac ipsum metus, a auctor massa. Nunc eros ante, ullamcorper a mollis nec, aliquam sed est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
          ac turpis egestas.</p>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/npfLjser/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because jquery is defined in the end. change order.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://enscrollplugin.com/releases/enscroll-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

Show [code snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/diegordzr/d8a83aLc/1/)

[image: jquery at top]

Comment: Thanks Diego! It worked out. I didn't know jQuery had to be placed first.